# FullCalendar addEventSource isn't working

Tags: fullcalendar

On page load I have a function that sets my event sources like this:

```
var source1 = {
    url: '/Feed1.aspx?param=abc',
    color: '#4793E6',
    textColor: 'black'
};

var source2 = {
    url: '/Feed2.aspx?param=abc',
    color: '#4793E6',
    textColor: 'black'
};
```

Then I create the FullCalendar doing something like this:

```
$('#Calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventSources: [
        source1,
        source2
    ]
});
```

This successfully loads both sources and renders the calendar. Then after changing a value using a drop-down on the page I want to remove source1 and source2, recreate them based on the changed value and refetch the events doing this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', source1);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', source2);

var source1 = {
    url: '/Feed1.aspx?param=defgh',
    color: '#4793E6',
    textColor: 'black'
};

var source2 = {
    url: '/Feed2.aspx?param=defgh',
    color: '#4793E6',
    textColor: 'black'
};

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', source1);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', source2);

/* According to the documentation this is NOT needed, but I tried anyway */
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

The event sources are successfully removed, but after changing the source values (using the same successful function as I do initially) and re-adding them, the fullCalendar doesn't try to fetch the events automatically which according to the [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/addEventSource/) it's supposed to and still doesn't when I manually call refectchEvents.

No JavaScript errors are being thrown it just doesn't properly alter the sources and/or refetch the events.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is it redisplaying the same information as before or is it not displaying anything?

Comment: Not displaying anything and according to Firebug no ajax call is being made

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo on the question or if it's actually in your code, but in your add and removes and everything you use `#calendar` and in your creation you use `#Calendar`. This would be a case sensitive field... but it would also cause an error in the console of firebug...

Comment: YARG! Thank-you...it was indeed the #Calendar typo :s The above code works perfectly when all of the ids are #calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer from comment**

Be careful to use case sensitivity when getting elements by Id.

Don't feel bad though, it happens to all of us at one time or another!